# Where the STOMP ACK frame goes to in RabbitMQ?

Tags: spring, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-rabbit

I have an app where I send messages over Stomp subscriptions. When messages are received, they send ACK frame. I'd like to handle this ack frame on server side, and my question is there any ack listener in rabbitmq or ack handler that will takes that frame and its headers? I'd like to access that frame to send some kind of confirmation to the producer that message was received.

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/'+ thread, function (greeting) {  
                var divId = "#userinfo";                    
                console.log("SENDING TO TOPIC/GREETING")
                showGreeting(divId, JSON.parse(greeting.body).person,
                JSON.parse(greeting.body).message);
                greeting.ack();
                }, {id: thread, ack:'client'});
```

```java
@MessageMapping("/message")  
public MessageTemplate send(MessageTemplate messageTemp) throws Exception {
    MessageTemplate message = new MessageTemplate(messageTemp.getPerson(), messageTemp.getMessage(), messageTemp.getTo());
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("amq.topic", messageTemp.getTo(), message);
    return message;
}
```

```
<<< MESSAGE
subscription:other
destination:/topic/other
message-id:T_other@@session-8-X11WtIiVQr-7UcONamng@@3
redelivered:false
__TypeId__:com.patrykmaryn.spring.second.springsecond.MessageTemplate
priority:0
persistent:true
content-encoding:UTF-8
content-type:application/json
content-length:46
```

```
>>> ACK
message-id:T_other@@session-8-X11WtIiVQr-7UcONamng@@3
subscription:other
```

**EDIT**

I thought I could use

```
@Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {   
        registration.interceptors(inBoundInterceptor);
    }
```

And then in

```
public class InboundMessagesChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

     @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel messageChannel) {
            // here's some logic to do with ACK frame like sending a 
            // notifiction message to the sender
            return message;
        }

}
```

However the method intercepts each inbound event, but I'd need only ACK message. In this case how could I get the ACK frame headers only?

Comment: Why do you want to send a message to the producer that the message has been received? This breaks a basic tenet of messaging that says producers and consumers should be logically disconnected from each other. Also, what kind of frame would the broker send to the producer for this? There's nothing in the STOMP specification for this kind of functionality.

Comment: How sender which is user in javascript client can be notified their message to 'topic' exchange was received?I'd like to send them a special message notification based on the ACK frame the receiver sent. I expect there's nothing in STOMP specification, but maybe in RabbitMQ. I want to achieeve messaging chat where a users sees if a message was received

Comment: There is no automated way for a sender to be notified that their message was received specifically because messaging brokers logically disconnect senders and consumers. Furthermore, since you're sending a message to a *topic* there is an arbitrary number of subscribers (i.e. there could be 0 or 100) so how will the sender know that *every* subscriber has received the message when there is no way for it to know how many subscribers there actually are?

Comment: Also, why specifically does the sender need to know its message was received in order to implement a chat application? There are lots of Javascript/STOMP chat examples on the web and I don't know any of them that require the sender to know when/if its message was received.

Comment: Given example shows sending ack on 'topic' exchange which actually might be overwhelmed. But i'd need to implement it to default exchange and use when sending private message, so there's only one receiver. I just gave an example. There are many chat apps where there's confirmation received when delivered.Something similar when you get Whatsapp double tick, or messenger timestamp when received, I wonder if it's possible to achieve something like this using websocket, stomp and rabbitmq

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as such to help others who may have this same question in the future. Otherwise, please clarify what is still lacking. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

The STOMP protocol has no support for telling a sender that their message has been acknowledged therefore you're going to need to implement your solution at the application level rather than at the protocol level. You can do this by implementing a [request/response pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response) in your sender and consumer.

This will, of course, significantly increase the amount of communication which your clients conduct which could potentially limit your application's scalability, but there's no way to avoid the communication overhead if you want this functionality with STOMP.